Connect ADS1298 to PC via USB
I designed an ECG board based on ADS1298 and schematics in this document (pages 52, 53, 55) with some customizations. I should connect it to PC via USB.
As I found here, TI evaluation board uses a DSP chip for this. I have no experience with these type of processors.
One solution is to use a microcontroller with SPI and USB peripherals. Needs some coding.
I also found MCP2210 USB-to-SPI chip. As far as I checked, everything is fine with it and I can connect it directly to ADS1298 SPI pins:

GND<>CS
MISO<>DOUT
SCK<>SCLK
MOSI<>DIN

this chip doesn't need any coding.
I will write a custom program to communicate with chip and not going to use ADS1298ECG-FE Evaluation Software.
Which solution is preferred and why? I personally think MCP2210 is the better solution but I want to know advice of experts.

It might be up to anyone's preference and opinions. You seem to prefer a solution based on the fact that it does not need any coding, except of course on the PC side, but you haven't told what you really need so it is unknown if the MCP2210 can do what you want, and it will always be a HID device. How do you intend to access the HID device in your code?

@Justme There are a lot of libraries in many programming languages for HID communication.


this chip doesn't need any coding.

that's wrong. You are ignoring the digital signals besides the SPI bus.
Your solution can't work; you need to have some deterministic-latency controller connected to the SPI interface to pull the data out as soon as the DRDY output of your EGC ADC signals available data. You can't do that via an USB-SPI converter.
So, you need some microcontroller that can react to interrupts signalled by the DRDY signal.
Luckily, ECG signals are low-bandwidth, so your chip only supplies a maximum total sampling rate of 32 kHz; even at full 24 bit resolution, a somewhat fast modern microcontroller with an integrated USB interface would do here (something like the ubiquitous Cortex-M4F chips would make sense, e.g., stm32f4*).
Going full microcontroller here seems to be the right choice here on multiple level: not only does it solve the interrupt / Data retrieval timing problem, it also allows for client-side buffering through in-MCU DMA buffers, and setting up isochronous transfers, so that you can be sure the USB bus is reserving enough bandwidth to query the microcontroller regularly. You'll want a microcontroller for setup of the ECG chip anyways – for example, there's a RESET signal that must not be deasserted before supply voltages have stabilized. Easy with a microcontroller!

I didn't notice DRDY signal. I found that GP6 is configurable as External Interrupt in MCP2210 (page 53 of datasheet). What if I poll on count of interrupts in PC and read data when it is greater than zero then reset count?
As you mentioned, ECG signals are low bandwidth; while USB has high bandwidth and low latency which makes it sufficient for polling in PC program.
For RESET, MCP2210 has some GPIOs, I can use one of them to reset ADS1298 when USB communication is ready (which means power and clock are stable).

Most MCUs have a 12Mbps USB built-in. The ECG chip has max data rate of 8 channels, 24 bits per channel, and 32000 samples per second, being 6.144 Mbps. That is quite a lot and takes more than 50% of the available bandwidth.

@Justme jep, that's why you don't try to do this on a cheap Cortex-M0. You'll really really need the DMA engines, and I mean plural, as you simply can't wait for the USB transfer to be done to fetch new data from the ADS1298. If things get to tight, cypress FX2 would be an option (in fact, that thing does power SDRs with up to 10 MS/s of 16bit samples), but then you really need to consider some buffering glue; and then you're darn close to putting a USB core on an FPGA; let's throw around some numbers: USB HS polling interval is 1ms, so we need to be able to buffer signal worth of ca 1.6 ms.

At 6.1422 Mbps, that's 6 kB of buffer (that's why I think the 4 kB FIFO in the FX2 won't cut it); but any FPGA fast enough to do the 12 Mbd USB brings more SRAM than that, so I'm relatively positive that one could adapt an existing design (like this) to the use case of shuffling data to a host.

The ADS1298 data rate is 250 SPS to 32kSPS. I don't think we need full 32kSPS. Using high performance MCU or FPGA is overcomplicating and unnecessary higher cost in my opinion.

@AmirSinaMashayekh but your opinion really won't matter; you'll need a microcontroller or FPGA to handle the timing-sensitive retrieval of data. And both can already do USB, so your MCP2210 is probably redundant.
